# Autoconfiguration class initialization order

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've written an auto-configuring library and would like to use it in a different project.

The trouble I'm having is the order of initializing this library. Currently, I am unable to get it working in one of my services, because it is being configured too late. I need this library to be initialized as early in the Spring context as possible.

Can I somehow manipulate this ordering? Note that I don't need, for example, a `@DependsOn` annotation as it doesn't work in the direction I'm interested in. With `@DependsOn` I can delay my autoconfiguration class, but I want to speed it up.

Comment: how the service is created and how its dependencies injected ? if you use the injection via constructor, there should be no problem !

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi this library is strictly for tests only, thus I use `@Autowired`. There's another autoconfiguration class (3rd party) that is initialized before mine autoconfig class. I need MINE before the 3rd party one.

Comment: have you tried the @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=3rdPartyClass.class) ?

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi Yes, this is currently what I'm experimenting with. However, this disables the `3rdPartyClass` completely, I need the 3rd party, but not before my library :)

Comment: it's seems your and other class implements the same interface, did they ?

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi No, my autoconfiguration class is configuring and starting the database Docker container. The 3rd party is Spring's autoconfiguration for this database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256711/discussion-between-stefano-riffaldi-and-icemajor).